# jQuery - Populate jqgrid with selected json data

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a grid with a custom button that displays another grid. I want to populate this second grid with some selected data from a .jsp file. My json is like this:

```
[{"codigo":"1","descricao":"Tec"},
 {"codigo":"2","descricao":"Inf"},
 {"codigo":"3","descricao":"Hw"}]
```

First grid should display the whole data (this is working) but the second grid should display only the data which "codigo == 2" for example... How can I make this selection?

Lucas.

Comment: you mean grid in a grid??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var grid = [{"codigo":"1","descricao":"Tec"},
 {"codigo":"2","descricao":"Inf"},
 {"codigo":"3","descricao":"Hw"}];

var selectGrid = [];

grid.forEach(function(item, index){
  if(item.codigo=='2') 
    selectGrid.push(item);
});
```

And then you can populate the second grid with the `selectGrid` data

Edit: You can use the `filter` method as well.

`selectGrid2 = grid.filter(function(item, index){return item.codigo=='2';});`